# How to model introduction rule for implication in Coq?

Tags: logic, coq, first-order-logic

I am learning natural deductions and practicing Coq.

We consider a formula:

```coq
Inductive P :=
| ...
| And: P -> P -> P
| Imp: P -> P -> P. (* implication *)
```

Now I add a bunch of inference rules for provability:

```coq
Inductive Deriv: P -> Prop :=
| ...
| intro_and: forall p q, Deriv p -> Deriv q -> Deriv (And p q)
| elim_and1: forall p q, Deriv (And p q) -> Deriv p
| elim_and2: forall p q, Deriv (And p q) -> Deriv q
| ...
```

But I am stuck with the introduction rule for implication. I tried this:

```coq
| intro_imp: forall p q, (Deriv p -> Deriv q) -> Deriv (Imp p q)
```

, which clearly does not work, because the inductive case appears in a negative position.

The introduction rule for implication is:

```
[p]
 .
 .
 q
-------
p ⊃ q
```

How would one model the introduction rule for implication in Coq?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formulating natural deduction as-is is a little bit difficult to do directly in Coq, because the most natural formulation keeps the premises hidden. Thus, we can't refer to the premise we're discharging when introducing the implication.

I think the simplest solution is to make the hypotheses *explicit* in the judgement, i.e. `Deriv` would have the type `list P -> P -> Prop`. The idea is that `Deriv hs p` expresses that `p` is provable *under hypotheses* `hs`. This means abandoning the original Hilbert-style formulation of natural deduction, where hypotheses are implicit (check e.g. [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus)). Staying within the fragment that you gave, this could result in something like this (using a sequent with just one conclusion):

```
Inductive Deriv : list P -> P -> Prop :=
(* How to use a hypothesis *)
| premise_intro hs p : In p hs -> Deriv hs p

(* In most rules, we just maintain the list of hypotheses *)
| and_intro hs p1 p2 : Deriv hs p1 -> Deriv hs p2 -> Deriv hs (And p1 p2)
| and_elim1 hs p1 p2 : Deriv hs (And p1 p2) -> Deriv hs p1
| and_elim2 hs p1 p2 : Deriv hs (And p1 p2) -> Deriv hs p2
| imp_elim hs p1 p2 : Deriv hs (Imp p1 p2) -> Deriv hs p1 -> Deriv hs p2

(* When introducing an implication, we remove the hypothesis from our list *)
| imp_intro hs p1 p2 : Deriv (p1 :: hs) p2 -> Deriv hs (Imp p1 p2).
```